# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Photography's [third moderator election](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: JoanneC]

She'll be joining [the existing crew](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank her for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with her as she learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/3).

Congratulations, Joanne!

Comment: Congratulations Joanne!

Comment: Thanks @MikeW appreciated! I'm looking forward to pitching in!

Comment: JoanneC: I promise to create some hilarious spam for you as soon as your title is handed over.

Comment: @dpollit LOL, I'm sure! I look forward to it

Comment: I've just flagged everything on the first three pages. Enjoy!

Comment: A true master flags the election results for the new mod. ;)

Comment: Apparently, I now have a lot to read! Homework at my age...

Comment: Congrats, Joanne! If you need any help, just let me know. There are a LOT of tools at your disposal now, not all of them obvious, but most of them are very useful.

Comment: @jrista - Need any help?!? Now that's an understatement! I'm just exploring and trying not to break anything right now...

Comment: Check out the custom content area. That is where we manage the PotW on the header. I usually take care of that, every Tuesday night (tonight, actually). Sometimes I miss it, though, and the winners usually don't like that as it cuts into their time on the header. Just keep an eye out on that, and if it isn't updated by Wednesday morning, it would be great if you could fill in for me.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget...your votes are now BINDING and INSTANTANEOUS! Don't vote unless you really have to. I usually wait for someone to flag before I do anything...outside of that, I let the community moderate itself. If I get a flag, my general M.O. is to add a "post notice", or comment, and give the member who questioned or answered a couple days to take action on their own before I make any binding action,.

Comment: Good advice. I did find the PotW header item, so I'll keep a watch.  You can also let me know ahead of time too, I don't mind. What time is usually? Like midnight (EST for me) or a little earlier?

Comment: I try to do it before I go to bed, which is usually a couple of hours before midnight MST. It doesn't have to be exact...I think the general rule of thumb is that the header is updated by the morning of the next day.

Comment: Cool, my morning is a bit earlier than you, so if it's not up by 6:30am EST, I'll do it (assuming I have Internet access).

Comment: Oh, and I'll probably bork it the first time... :p